# Question about a proof of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+i)\cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

Proof:

> Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$,
>   where $i$ and $x$ correspond,
>
> we have: $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+i)\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1,2+x)$.
>
> In that ring, since $x=-2$, $x^2+1=5$, and
>
> $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1,2+x)\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(5,2+x)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]/(2+x)\cong \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$,
>
> since $x=-2$ is in the quotient ring.

Source: problem 1b in https://sites.math.washington.edu/~sullivan/4034s_wi13.pdf

**My questions:**

-What is meant by $i$ and $x$ correspond? Why is $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(2+i)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1,2+x)$. Why is it okay to just replace $i$ with $x$? I understand the $\mathbb{Z}[i]\cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ part.

-Why is $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]/(2+x)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$? T tried but I can't find a homomorphism whose kernel would be $(2+x)$.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- $i$ is the solution to the equation $x^2+1=0$. When you consider $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and mod out by the ideal $(x^2+1)$, you are creating a new ring in which $x^2+1=0$, that is, you're saying that $x$ satiesfies $x^2+1=0$, so $x$ corresponds to $i$.
- $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(i+2)\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+1)}/(x+2)\cong\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1,x+2)$
- Modding out by $(x+2)$, means that you're forming a new ring in which $x=-2$, but $-2$ is already inside $\mathbb{Z}_5$, so you're not getting anything new.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. $-i$ is also a solution to $x^2+1=0$.Why does $x$ not correspond to $-i$? Also when you say modding out by $(x+2)$, it's understood in $(\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z})[x]$ so what do you mean I'm not getting anything new? Can you give me an example of a $p(x)$ that would get me something new?

Comment: $-i$ is also $\in\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$, since $-1\in\mathbb{Z}$. You can think of modding out by the ideal $(x+2)$ as setting $x=-2$. This means that you get a new ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[-2]$. But here $-2\in\mathbb{Z}_5$ so $\mathbb{Z}_5[-2]=\mathbb{Z}_5$. You are getting a new element, however, with say $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-2)$. This is because $x^2-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, and so you're adding the element $\sqrt{2}$, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-2)\cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$. Notice that $-\sqrt{2}$ is also in this ring, since you can multiply with $-1$.

Answer (score 3):

For your second question: what about

$$\phi:\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z[x]\to\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\phi(p(x)):=p(-2)\;\;?$$

This is just the evaluation homomorphism (chech it is a ring homomorphism!) ,and its kernel is the set (ideal, in fact) of all polynomials in $\;\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z[x]\;$ which vanish at $\;x=-2\;$ ...